# Api call returns invalid region (US) when trying to compile app for deployment to Heroku despite having set the region to EU

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am trying to deploy my application to Heroku. I am using an external api which is blocked for the region US. I therefore created my application with the region eu with Heroku.

Despite this I still get back a 300 response rerouting to a page stating that I try to access the API from the US which is a blocked region. Any idea why this still happens despite having set the region to EU? Are there any solutions or add ons for this?

Edit: the API call is made from the Ruby back end using the Faraday gem
Edit: heroku info shows that the region is correctly set to eu

Comment: You need to tell how the API call is made, whether from the backend ruby code or front-end javascript.

Comment: Added this to the description, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I did not find an appropriate solution for this but decided to deploy at scalingo, which works fine

Answer (score 0):

First [verify your app's region](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/regions#verify-an-app-s-region):

```
heroku info
```

Heroku uses dynamic IP addresses, so you'll need to check w/ your API provider because they might not recognize or may actively block the IP addresses that Heroku is using.

You might want to use an addon or service like [Proximo](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/proximo) so you can have a static IP address for making requests to APIs and then you can ask them to whitelist the IP address for you if it doesn't already work.